# Copy subdirs + files from storage acct to ADX using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, file-copying

I'm trying to copy files from Az Storage blob to ADX using Data factory, but I can't find a solution to do this using json datasets (not binary), so I can map schema. I would love to have a template to do this.

I have tried to follow the resolution mentioned here ([Get metadata from Blob storage with "folder like structure" using Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688135/get-metadata-from-blob-storage-with-folder-like-structure-using-azure-data-fac)), but I'm lacking some more guidance (this is my first project using ADF)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGrMp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6I2k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8esWL.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you have shared, it seems like your dynamic expression for passing the childItems of your get metadata activity to ForEach activity `items` is causing this problem.

You might be using `Items` = `@activity('GetMetadataActivity').output` instead of `@activity('GetMetadataActivity').output.childItems`.

Please use `Items` = `@activity('GetMetadataActivity').output.childItems` in your ForEach activity which should help resolve your error.

Here is a video demonstration by a community volunteer where this error has been explained in detail: [ADF Error Function Length expects its parameter to be array or string](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XP9xmt5pzQ0)

Comment: Demonstration video link to overcome this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XP9xmt5pzQ0

Answer (score 0):

Now I am getting another error as shown below

I'm actually also looking for a COMPLETE guide setting this up.

Here is my overall use-case target https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/store-logs-in-azure-data-explorer?tabs=azure-storage-azure-data-factory - but the documentation is missing the detailed steps - in step 6 Create a data pipeline with a copy activity, based on when the blob properties were last modified. This step requires an extra understanding of Azure Data Factory. For more information, see Copy activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRXlq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylLzc.png)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Consider editing your original question, or posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as I was going in a wrong direction.

I have actually found a simple solution for setting this up. I have tried the copy data tool, and it seems to be doing what I want. So case closed :-)

Comment: Yes, if your requirement is to copy files from folders and subfolders recursively, then you can just use the copy activity recursive settings as shown in example of the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#folder-and-file-filter-examples

Comment: thx everyone for assisting me. I have now made an article on this https://www.linkedin.com/posts/mortenwaltorpknudsen_how-to-save-by-storing-your-syslog-and-activity-7019431014515011586-FlT7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop